# Removing minimal letters from a string 'A' to remove all instances of string 'B'

Tags: string, algorithm

If we have string `A` of length N and string `B` of length M, where M < N, can I quickly compute the minimum number of letters I have to remove from string `A` so that string `B` does not occur as a substring in `A`?

If we have tiny string lengths, this problem is pretty easy to brute force: you just iterate a bitmask from `0` to `2^N` and see if `B` occurs as a substring in this subsequence of `A`. However, when N can go up to 10,000 and M can go up to 1,000, this algorithm obviously falls apart quickly. Is there a faster way to do this?

Example: A=`ababaa` B=`aba`. Answer=`1`.Removing the second `a` in A will result in `abbaa`, which does not contain `B`.

**Edit:** User n.m. posted a great counter example: `aabcc` and `abc`. We want to remove the single `b`, because removing any `a` or `c` will create another instance of the string `abc`.

Comment: Probably KMP algorithm will help?

Comment: @nhahtdh How so? I'm not very familiar with the KMP algorithm, sorry.

Comment: Mostly for searching for string M in N, and allow overlapping substring. Worse case, it can go up to M^2 (since I search for the overlapping matches), but I don't think it will be a problem. The problem is how to remove character optimally, knowing all the positions of the matches.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm provides a thorough description and examples of the KMP algorithm. I agree that the mechanism for that algorithm provides valuable insights for this problem because the pre-computed table indicates the number of characters in `A` that one can skip over before re-trying a match for `B`.

Comment: I've read about KMP in the CLRS book in class, but have never implemented it. How can we decide which letter to remove at each step though?

Comment: I think that, based on the KMP algorithm, removing the last character of `B` from each instance of `B` in `A` should be optimal if there are no overlapping instances of `B`. If there are overlapping instances of `B`, one would have to remove up to `p+1` characters, where `p` is the length of the overlap, the worst case being where `B` is a string that comprises repeating patterns of the same characters.

Comment: Yes, the worst case would be strings that are `aaaaaaaa...`.

Comment: Added a sample to explain problem better.

Comment: "removing the last character of B" --- A="abcccccc", B="abc".

Comment: @n.m.: Excellent counterexample. I hadn't taken into account all the strings into which `A` might be transformed as a result of removing characters from it. There are probably several different cases where removing a character of `B` from `A` to prevent one match could create another match that wasn't there before. e.g. A = "aabcc", B = "abc" -- removing either "a" or "c" still leaves a match, so the minimal change would be to remove "b".

Comment: Also A=`aaabbb` and B=`ab`. Since KMP can find matches in O(N), but we potentially have to remove N letters, so that won't work, right?

Comment: a_trie: Can you avoid discussing USACO problems until after the contest is over?

Comment: For those who may be interested in the solution to this USACO problem, it is at http://www.usaco.org/current/data/sol_necklace.html.

Comment: This is very easy, you don't want B to appear in A, look for B occurrence in A, and do something about it ..

Answer (score 2):

Solve it with dynamic programming. Let dp[i][j] the minimum operator to make A[0...i-1] have a suffix of B[0...j-1] as well as A[0...i] doesn't contain B, `dp[i][j] = Infinite` to index the operator is impossible. Then

```
if(A[i-1]=B[i-1]) 
   dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i-1][j])    
else dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j]`,

return min(A[N][0],A[N][1],...,A[N][M-1]);`
```

Comment: totally a dynamic programming problem!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a graph search on the string `A`. This is probably too slow for large N and special input but it should work better than an exponential brute force algorithm. Maybe a BFS.

Comment: Yes this might work for small N but still, it's too slow for A=`..aaaaaaa..` and B=`a`

Comment: @a_trie So you also want it to handle strings of infinite length?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not  sure this question is still of someone interest, but I have an idea that maybe could work.

once we decided that the problem is not to find the substring, is to decide which letter is more convenient to remove from string A, the solution to me appears pretty simple: if you find an occurrence of B string into A, the best thing you can do is just remove a char that is inside the string, closed to the right bondary...let say the one previous the last. That's why if you have a substring that actually end how it starts, if you remove a char at the beginning you just remove one of the B occurencies, while you can actually remove two at once.

Algorithm in pseudo cose:

```
String A, B;
int occ_posit = 0;
N = B.length();

occ_posit = A.getOccurrencePosition(B); // pseudo function that get the first occurence of B into A and returns the offset (1° byte = 1), or 0 if no occurence present.

while (occ_posit > 0)  // while there are B into A
{
    if (B.firstchar == B.lastchar)  // if B starts as it ends
    {
        if (A.charat[occ_posit] == A.charat[occ_posit+1])
            A.remove[occ_posit - 1]; // no reason to remove A[occ_posit] here
        else
            A.remove[occ_posit]; // here we remove the last char, so we could remove 2 occurencies at the same time
    }
    else
    {
        int x = occ_posit + N - 1;
        while (A.charat[x + 1] == A.charat[x])
            x--; // find the first char different from the last one

        A.remove[x]; // B does not ends as it starts, so if there are  overlapping instances they overlap by more than one char. Removing the first that is not equal to the char following B instance, we kill both occurrencies at once.
    }
}
```

Let's explain with an example:

A = "123456789000987654321"
B = "890"

read this as a table:

```
occ_posit:  123456789012345678901

       A = "123456789000987654321"
       B =        "890"
```

first occurrence is at occ_posit = 8. B does not end as it starts, so it get into the second loop:

```
int x = 8 + 3 - 1 = 10;
while (A.charat[x + 1] == A.charat[x])
    x--; // find the first char different from the last one
A.remove[x];
```

the while find that A.charat11 matches A.charat[10] (="0"), so x become 9 and then while exits as A.charat[10] does not match A.charat9. A then become:

A = "12345678000987654321"

with no more occurencies in it.

Let's try with another:
A = "abccccccccc"
B = "abc"

first occurrence is at occ_posit = 1. B does not end as it starts, so it get into the second loop:

```
int x = 1 + 3 - 1 = 3;
while (A.charat[x + 1] == A.charat[x])
    x--; // find the first char different from the last one
A.remove[x];
```

the while find that A.charat4 matches A.charat[3] (="c"), so x become 2 and then while exits as A.charat[3] does not match A.charat2. A then become:

A = "accccccccc"

let's try with overlapping:

A = "abcdabcdabff"
B = "abcdab"

the algorithm results in: A = "abcdacdabff" that has no more occurencies.

finally, one letter overlap:

A = "abbabbabbabba"
B = "abba"

B end as it starts, so it enters the first if:

```
if (A.charat[occ_posit] == A.charat[occ_posit+1])
            A.remove[occ_posit - 1]; // no reason to remove A[occ_posit] here
        else
            A.remove[occ_posit]; // here we remove the last char, so we could remove 2 occurencies at the same time
```

that lets the last "a" of B instance to be removed. So:

1° step: A= "abbbbabbabba"
2° step: A= "abbbbabbbba" and we are done.

Hope this helps

EDIT: pls note that the algotirhm must be corrected a little not to give error when you are close to the A end with your search, but this is just an easy  programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch I've come up with.

First, if A contains any symbols that are not found in B, split up A into a bunch of smaller strings containing only those characters found in B. Apply the algorithm on each of the smaller strings, then glue them back together to get the total result. This really functions as an optimization.

Next, check if A contains any of B. If there isn't, you're done. If A = B, then delete all of them.

I think a relatively greedy algorithm may work.

First, mark all of the symbols in A which belong to at least one occurrence of B. Let A = aabcbccabcaa, B = abc. Bolding indicates these marked characters:

a **abc** bcc **abc** aa. If there's an overlap, mark all possible. This operation is naively approximately (A-B) operations, but I believe it can be done in around (A/B) operations.

Consider the deletion of each marked letter in A: a **abc** bcc **abc** aa.

Check whether the deletion of that marked letter decreases the number of marked letters. You only need to check the substrings which could possibly be affected by the deletion of the letter. If B has a length of 4, only the substrings starting at the following locations would need to be deleted if x were being checked:

```
-------x------
    ^^^^
```

Any further left or right will exist regardless of the presence of x.

For instance:

Marking the [a] in the following string: a **[a]bc** bcc **abc** aa.

Its deletion yields abcbccabcaa, which when marked produces **abc** bcc **abc** aa, which has an equal number of marked characters. Since only the relative number is required for this operation, it can be done in approximately 2B time for each selected letter. For each, assign the relative difference between the two. Pick an arbitrary one which is maximal and delete it. Repeat until done. Each pass is roughly up to 2AB operations, for a maximum of A passes, giving a total time of about 2A^2 B.

In the above example, these values are assigned:

```
aabcbccabcaa
 033   333
```

So arbitrarily deleting the first marked b gives you: aacbccabcaa. If you repeat the process, you get:

```
aacbccabcaa
      333
```

The final result is done.

I believe the algorithm is correctly minimal. I think it is true that whenever A requires only one deletion, the algorithm *must* be optimal. In that case, the letter which reduces the most possible matches (ie: all of them) should be best. I can come up with no such proof, though. I'd be interested in finding any counter-examples to optimality.

Answer (score 0):

Find the indeces of each substring in the main string.

Then using a dynamic programming algorithm (so memoize intermediate values), remove each letter that is part of a substring from the main string, add 1 to the count, and repeat.

You can find the letters, because they are within the indeces of each match index + length of B.

```
A = ababaa
B = aba
count = 0

indeces = (0, 2)

A = babaa, aabaa, abbaa, abbaa, abaaa, ababa
B = aba
count = 1

(2nd abbaa is memoized)

indeces = (1), (1), (), (), (0), (0, 2)

answer = 1
```

You can take it a step further, and try to memoize the substring match indeces of substrings, but that might not actually be a performance gain.

Not sure on the exact bounds, but shouldn't take too long computationally.